# Creating table by column rather than by row

Tags: c#, .net, razor

I have a list of objects that I need to print things from their list in a table, to compare feature A to feature B.

However, as it is right now, when doing the table rendering, all the items from A are in a row and all the items from B are in a row, rather than A items in a column and B items in the next column.

I'm doing something like..

```
<div style="display: table;">
     @foreach(var OuterItem in Outer) {
         <div style="table-row">
             @foreach(var InnerItem in OuterItem.SubItems) {
             <div style="table-cell">
                 @Html.Raw(InnerItem.Property)
             </div>
             }
         </div>
     }
</div>
```

Which would produce something that looks like

```
| A1 | A2 | A3|
| B1 | B2 | B3|
```

But the table I'm looking for is..

```
| A1 | B2 |
| A2 | B2 |
| A3 | B3 |
```

Is there a way to do my looping that would produce that table?

Transposing the data seems unnecessary as well, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the backing structure is for your `Outer` and the `SubItems` collections. If they are indexable and have the same number of `SubItems`, than you could perhaps do something like this:

```
<div style="display: table;">
     @for(var j = 0; j < Outer[0].SubItems.Count; j++) {
       <div style="table-row">
          @for(var i = 0; i < Outer.Count; i++) {             
             <div style="table-cell">
                 @Html.Raw(Outer[i].SubItems[j].Property)
             </div>
          }
        </div>
     }
</div>
```

On a small scale, and assuming you always have at least one `Outer` item, this should be fine but from a performance stand-point accessing the items out of order like that is not very (memory) cache friendly.

It might be best to leave the loop structure you had originally and just redesign your HTML using CSS to position the two columns side-by-side:

```
<div id="container">
     @for(var j = 0; j < Outer[0].SubItems.Count; j++) {
       <div style="tablecolumn">
          @for(var i = 0; i < Outer.Count; i++) {             
             <div class="tablecell">
                 @Html.Raw(Outer[i].SubItems[j].Property)
             </div>
          }
        </div>
     }

     <!-- make sure the container layout is displayed correctly by adding a clear fix -->
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

And style the `tablecolumn` and `tablecell` in CSS to display the elements in a vertical column. I think the most important thing is to make sure the `tablecell` elements all have the same height so as not to have missalignments.

```
.tablecolumn {
     float: left;
     width: 49%;
}

.tablecell {
     height: 25px;   /* or whatever value you find appropriate */
}
```